# Sequence of sorted numbers to ranges

Tags: unix, awk, sed

I have a huge text file with sorted numbers in each line. I'd like to transform it into chunk of ranges using sed or awk.
For instance:

```
1
2
3
5
6
9
11
12
```

Should be transformed into:

```
1-3
5-6
9
11-12
```

Is that reasonable to use sed for such transformation?

Comment: pain-in-the-ass with sed to do

Comment: could be but because sed cannot count, it's hard and CPU extensive  where a awk will do it *finger in the nose*

Comment: Thank you guys, awk is fine as well. I added the tag for awk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one `awk` solution:

```
awk 'NR==1 {printf $0} p+1!=$0 {printf "-"p"\n"$0} {p=$0} END {print "-"$0}' file
1-3
5-6
9-9
11-12
```

This assume that all lines does have numbers and they increases for every line.

---

To be more portable/correct with  `printf`

```
awk 'NR==1 {printf "%s",$0} p+1!=$0 {printf "-%s\n%s",p,$0} {p=$0} END {print "-"$0}'
```

Comment: Just to share some details. The input file had 2.2 billion lines, the output only 57k...and it has terminated in 38 minutes. Awesome :)

Answer (score 0):

Perl solution:

```
perl -lne 'sub out { print $first == $prev ? $first : "$first-$prev" } # Produce the output.
           if ($_ != $prev+1 and defined $first) {                     # Current number not in seq.
               out();                                                  # Output the previous seq.
               $first = $_;                                            # Start a new one.
           }
           $prev  = $_;                                                # Remember the current number.
           $first = $_ if !defined $first;                             # Initialize for the first line.
           }{ out()                                                    # Output the last sequence.
          ' input.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys, bash solution:

```bash
A=`head -n1 data.txt`
B=$A
while read LINE
do
    if [[ `expr $LINE - $B` != 1 ]]
    then
        if [[ "$A" != "$B" ]]
        then
            echo "-$B"
        else
            echo
        fi
        A=$LINE
        echo -n "$A"
    fi
    B=$LINE
done < data.txt
```